# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header()

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress website and have come across a critical error:I have created a header.php file and tried using the get_header() function to import the header into all of my pages. In my index.php page it works perfectly, but in all of my other pages, I get an error message saying “Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header()”. For experimental purposes, the code in my index.php page is the same as in all of my other .php pages. What am I doing wrong? Here Is the code for one of my pages “feedback.php”:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Import Header from header.php -->
<?php get_header() ?>    
<title> Home </title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Notable&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<h2> Hello World </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is `feedback.php` accessed? Is it a page template, or loaded directly (ex: example.com/wp-content/themes/theme/feedback.php)? If it's accessed directly, then WordPress isn't being loaded, which is why `get_header()` is undefined.

Comment: Looks like a include is missing.

Comment: @Caleb, the feedback.php is loaded directly. What is the other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `feedback.php` is being accessed directly, which doesn't load WordPress. This is why `get_header()` is undefined.

Depending on the purpose of `feedback.php`, you may want to use it as a page template (most common), or load WordPress on top of it.

For using as a page template (most use-cases, and likely yours), read this official WordPress Developer Resource article: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/.

If you do want to load WordPress on top of the file (uncommon), then you'll need to include the `wp-load.php` file (root of WordPress install) at the top of the file.